# Angularstrap modal doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

When I trying to show a modal window in Angularjs Application with AngularStrap, I am always getting an error saying "Cannot set property 'zIndex' of undefined". 
My code is below:

```
var storageModal = $modal({
scope : $scope, 
templateUrl : 'sections/modals/storage.modal.tpl.html', 
show : false });

$scope.showStorageModal = function() {
console.log('Modal Show');
storageModal.$promise.then(storageModal.show);
};
```

Is there anyone who can help me? Thank you for your help in advance...

Comment: are you applying any css property?

Comment: No. I am just using bootstrap.css.